# duplicate frame without creating new controls

Tags: labview

I have a stacked sequence and I want to duplicate a frame. However, when I do this, all my controls and indicators get copied. Is there any way to have all those copies be local variables instead? I don't want to have to go through each control and indicator and make it local variable that points to the original frame control/indicator.
thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as far as I know. I have this issue as well, but only in one case, when I duplicate an event in events structure. It is not to many situation exists in LabVIEW when a control or indicator is located inside a structure and this structure should be duplicated.
I don't like to be didactic, but what you described is considered a bad programming practice in LabVIEW. Stacked sequence is a most discrepant structure in LabVIEW, many people are never used it. I can not remember a case, where a stacked sequence must be used. It can always be replaced by flat sequence and flat sequence is not required in many cases either, dataflow serve you as a sequence. 
Local variable should never be abused either. Literally saying, there is no concept of variables in LabVIEW. Wire is your variable to some extent. So, if you need to program a sequence and use your control's value - use a wire. If you need to program states - use state machine and your variable will be a shift register.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this.

PS: it looks like your code is a big frame with lot of code and control. Maybe you should clean this a bit...